# Output logic for all collected data in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, logic

I have a PS script I've created to connect to an XML sheet and collect the nodes I need, makes modifications/conversions and then I'm attempting to put it into one list using $books | Format-Table. However this ends up putting the header over each entry, when I output to a textile I had it do a newline and append, is this possible using the table function or is it something I would need to call outside the foreach loop? Im new to programming in general so I'm sure I'm just missing something.

I'm ending up with:

```
Column 1
========
123456

Column 1
========
123456
```

But looking for:

```
Column 1
========
123456
123456
```

```
cls


$storenum = Read-Host -Prompt 'Store Number'
$data = Read-Host -Prompt 'SKUS'
$foos = ($data | select-string -pattern '\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{10}' -AllMatches).Matches.Value  

#|\d{10}



foreach ($foo in $foos) {
[xml]$books = (Invoke-webrequest -URI "http://st${storenum}.server/info?sku=${foo}").Content


#Meet conditions for matches, SKU is set
    if ($books.ItemInfoResponse.results.skuNumber -gt "0")
  {

$books | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property SKU,
@{Label="SKU"; Expression={$books.ItemInfoResponse.results.skuNumber}},
@{Label="Description"; Expression={$books.ItemInfoResponse.results.skuDescription}}

}}
```

Comment: That means you're either outputting something _other than_ the objects with a `Column 1` property, and PowerShell's formatting system tries to break up the output to ensure nothing is lost; or you explicitly asked PowerShell to format an expression prior to the last output. Show us your script if you want help pinpointing which and where :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i added the script above

Answer (score 1):

Only use format-table once or not at all.